# App maker trigger sends mail two times from my 2 different Email addresses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-app-maker

I had write one Trigger in my App maker project.
This trigger call one function.
In this function i have write one filter to get data from google cloud SQL and send mail to different user.
I am using MailApp.SendMail() function to send email.

In this trigger i am written script for sending mail once in a day.

This is my Triggers code:-

```
function Triggercreate()
{
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('filtterFunction') 
       .timeBased() 
       .everyDays(1)
       .create();          
}
```

This Triggercreate() call inside button Click event.
I had deploy this project and share with my another user in same domain.
and set run this deployment as user Account

After deploying and sharing this app, I had open deployed project with user account and click this button to creating trigger.
Now regularly trigger is runs but it send mail from both user and developer Email address
But i want to send mail from only my user Email Address.
please give me solution for this problem...

I had purchased Business G-suit for my both Emails.
I have already set setting as mention in - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/identity

Answer (score 0):

look at the script from  the developer account and manually delete the trigger

Comment: Thanks dear. I am already deleted my developers accounts trigger. Now in Developers account no trigger is present. Only in user account 3- trigger present.Still email comes from both the email account.